# How can I get the list of registered atexit functions in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I can use the [atexit](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/atexit.html) module to register function to be executed when Python exits. Is there a way to retrieve the list of registered exit handlers?

Comment: Note that [`weakref.finalize`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize) can also *de facto* lead to function calls when Python exits, if garbage collection does not occur any earlier, so even if you do find a list of `atexit` handlers, you might still not find everything.

Comment: And there's something in the `multiprocessing` module too outputting debug messages such as `[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers`, I'm not sure where exactly that is coming from, but there may be something there as well, for some cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2, where the module is still available as a Python-only, the `atexit` module has a semi-private list:

```
atexit._exithandlers
```

which holds all registered exit handlers.

In Python 3, the module has been re-coded in C and the list is no longer accesible, so for Python 3 you are flat out of luck, I am afraid.

You'd have to port the [Python 2 pure-python version](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/atexit.py) to Python 3, and ensure that it is used instead of the C version to make the list accessible again.

Comment: You could, however, monkey-patch the `atexit` module to keep your own list of handlers before calling the library functions.

Comment: @kindall: No, you cannot. It is a C module, those cannot be monkey-patched.

Comment: Sure you can, you just have to replace the whole module in `sys.modules`. Which is simple enough, because there are only two functions in the module.

Comment: @kindall: You could in principle swap out `sys.modules['atexit']` for your own version dynamically, but if *any* code ran and registered a handler before your code can do that then at worst those functions may end up being ignored, at best you missed that they were registered.

Comment: Yes, clearly you'd have to do this before you import anything else that has a chance to register anything.

Comment: Right, at which point you may as well just replace `atexit` with a python implementation, which then is imported instead of the C extension.

Answer (score 23):

here is a pure-python way to access the registered functions (the callable objects), but not the arguments they would be called with. It's a bit of a hack, but for debugging and the like, it will do just fine :

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jul  9 2020, 13:00:10) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import atexit
>>> class Capture:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.captured = []
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         self.captured.append(other)
...         return False
... 
>>> c = Capture()
>>> atexit.unregister(c)
>>> print(c.captured)
[<function <lambda> at 0x7fc47631d730>, <built-in function write_history_file>]
>>> atexit.unregister(c.captured[0])  # this will work
```

How it works: as documented, `atexit.unregister(c)` removes any occurrence of `c` from the callback list. It does so by comparing each callback in turn with `c` for equality. This leads to the call `c.__eq__(other)`, with `other` being the callback (this call is never skipped, as the other way around raises `NotImplemented`). `Capture.__eq__` then copies its argument.

Comment: I love this solution, very clever.

Answer (score 7):

here's the solution provided by @BCarvello in a functional form:

```
import atexit


def get_atexit_functions():
    funs = []

    class Capture:
        def __eq__(self, other):
            funs.append(other)
            return False

    c = Capture()
    atexit.unregister(c)
    return funs
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, atexit._exithandlers list is not available but if you just need to count the callbacks registered, you can do like this :

```
atexit._ncallbacks()
```

Demo :

```
# python3
Python 3.5.3rc1 (default, Jan  3 2017, 04:40:57) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20161229] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import atexit
>>> atexit._ncallbacks()
2
```

Comment: This appears to be the count of the number of atexit handlers ever registered, rather than the count of the number of handlers that will run at exit. The difference is that if you ever unregister an atexit handler, the `_ncallbacks()` result doesn't go down to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open feature request to expose this information ([bpo-32082](https://bugs.python.org/issue32082)). That request references a workaround in the form of a Cython module [here](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/b5c9cf037cbce672101725f269470135b9b2c5c4/src/sage/cpython/atexit.pyx#L171), the critical piece of which is:

```
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject

# Internal structures defined in the CPython source in
# Modules/atexitmodule.c and subject to (but unlikely to) change.  Watch
# https://bugs.python.org/issue32082 for a request to (eventually)
# re-expose more of the atexit module's internals to Python
ctypedef struct atexit_callback:
    PyObject* func
    PyObject* args
    PyObject* kwargs


ctypedef struct atexitmodule_state:
    atexit_callback** atexit_callbacks
    int ncallbacks
    int callback_len


cdef extern from "Python.h":
    void* PyModule_GetState(object module)


def _get_exithandlers():
    """Return list of exit handlers registered with the atexit module."""
    cdef atexitmodule_state* state
    cdef atexit_callback callback
    cdef list exithandlers
    cdef int idx
    cdef object kwargs

    state = <atexitmodule_state*>PyModule_GetState(atexit)

    if not state:
        raise RuntimeError("atexit module state missing or corrupt")

    exithandlers = []

    for idx in range(state.ncallbacks):
        callback = state.atexit_callbacks[idx][0]
        if callback.kwargs:
            kwargs = <object>callback.kwargs
        else:
            kwargs = {}
        exithandlers.append((<object>callback.func,
                             <object>callback.args,
                             kwargs))
    return exithandlers
```